# How to concatenate two JSX fragment or variables or string and component (in Reactjs)?

Tags: reactjs, concatenation, jsx

I know JSX can be very misleading because it looks like strings and it is not, thus the "string" term in the question, even if we are not really manipulating strings.

Here is a code example (wrong, obviously):

```
let line = <Line key={line.client_id} line={line}/>;
if(line.created_at) {
    return <div className="date-line"><strong>{line.created_at}</strong></div> + line;
} else {
    return chat_line;
}
```

I have a line, and I want to "concatenate" some divs in front of it under certain conditions. What would be the proper syntax?
I've tried parenthesis, brackets, plus sign... None of them seem to work...

thanks

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Use arrays:

```
let lineComponent = <Line key={line.client_id} line={line}/>;
if (line.created_at) {
  return [
    <div key="date" className="date-line"><strong>{line.created_at}</strong></div>,
    lineComponent,
  ];
} else {
  return chat_line;
}
```

Or use fragments:

```
import createFragment from "react-addons-create-fragment";

let lineComponent = <Line key={line.client_id} line={line}/>;
if (line.created_at) {
  return createFragment({
    date: <div className="date-line"><strong>{line.created_at}</strong></div>,
    lineComponent: lineComponent,
  });
} else {
  return chat_line;
}
```

In both cases, you have to **provide keys for React**. In case of array, you set key directly on element. Regarding fragments, you provide key:element pairs.

NOTE:
**When returning from `render`  method, you can only return single element, or `NULL`.** Examples provided are invalid in that case.

Comment: yep, indeed the array technique is working. That's a bit weird at first, but at least, you can format it line by line to have something looking like HTML. Quite neat. Thx !

Comment: in real world usage, I prefer fragments. Just a personal preference :)

Comment: Good to know is that using the Array method will force you to have the unique key attribute.

Answer (score 21):

For React Native, I prefer this technique:

1. pro: in contrast to the array technique you don't have to artificially create keys
2. con: requires the overhead of a containing element (e.g., View, *below*)

```js
jsx = <Text>first</Text>;
jsx = <View>{jsx}<Text>second</Text></View>;
```

Answer (score 17):

You can use empty tags, I mean, `<>` and `</>`, whenever you just don't want any additional `Container-Element` (e.g. `<View>`), like below:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Text>First</Text>

        <Text>Second</Text>
      </>
    );
  }
```

### Example:

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'

import Reinput from 'reinput'

export default class ReinputWithHeader extends Reinput {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <View style={{backgroundColor: 'blue', flexDirection: 'row', alignSelf: 'stretch', height: 20}}>
          <Text>Blue Header</Text>
        </View>

        {super.render()}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

> Note: I tested and it works on `react-native` too; see also [Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html).

#### Preview:

[image]

Comment: haha Oh wow!! This is so sneaky that I feel like I'm going to get in trouble. Ultimately I'm going to use `React.Fragment` but this is great.

Comment: I use it as        <>New Transaction<div className='btn_key'>F4</div></>   and it help me a lot.

Answer (score 12):

It is possible to use an **Array** and push **jsx** code there.
For example:

```
   function App() {

      function cells() {
        const size = 10;
        const cells = [];
        for (let i=0; i<size; i++) {
          cells.push(
            <tr>
              <td>Hello World</td>
            </tr>
          )
        }
        return cells;
      }

      return (
        <table>
          <tbody>
            {cells()}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay using a parent object such as another div you can also do it this way:

```
let line = <Line key={line.client_id} line={line}/>;
if(line.created_at) {
    return <div><div className="date-line"><strong>{line.created_at}</strong></div>{line}</div>;
} else {
    return chat_line;
}
```