# Using additional checks with the logical AND operator to render data without crashing on page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, logical-operators

When I refreshed the page my app crashes. This was due to my page loading in faster than my data. I think... So I added additional checks using the logical AND (&&) operator. Is this best practice? It just seems odd to have to do this everywhere. Is there a better, more practical way around this?

I was just messing around with how I fetch APIs. This isn't from any special project of mine just a little sandbox file.

This is what the code looked like when it was crashing on page refresh:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Heading } from "./components/Heading";

const URL = "https://api.sleeper.app/v1/league/867824542855376896";

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(URL);
      const data = await res.json();
      setData(data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  console.log(data);
  return (
    <>
      <Heading str="Hello world" />
      <Heading str="Hello friend" />
      <h1>{data.bracket_id}</h1>
      {data.roster_positions.map((pos, i) => {
          return <h1 key={i + 1}>{pos}</h1>;
        })}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And this is what I did to fix it...

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Heading } from "./components/Heading";

const URL = "https://api.sleeper.app/v1/league/867824542855376896";

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(URL);
      const data = await res.json();
      setData(data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  console.log(data);
  return (
    <>
      <Heading str="Hello world" />
      <Heading str="Hello friend" />
      <h1>{data && data.bracket_id}</h1>
      {data &&
        data.roster_positions.map((pos, i) => {
          return <h1 key={i + 1}>{pos}</h1>;
        })}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Is there a better way of doing this beside add a logical AND operator before every use of my data?

Comment: Update Code is Also Fine But You Can Modify Some Code

Answer (score 0):

Here I Have Made Some Update on Your Code On Mine Experience Which i have faced issue previously so i write code like this

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Heading } from "./components/Heading";

const URL = "https://api.sleeper.app/v1/league/867824542855376896";

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({}); // instead of using null use {}
  // Some Time Function Call inside useEffect Become A Cause of Error

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(URL);
      const data = await res.json();
      setData(data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
    // Add Condition Here
    if ( data === {} && data.length === 0 ) {
       getData();
       console.log(data);
    }
    
  }, []); // Add Rest Dependency Here

  
  return (
    <>
      <Heading str="Hello world" />
      <Heading str="Hello friend" />
      <h1>{data && data.bracket_id}</h1>
      {data && data.length > 0 &&
        data?.roster_positions.map((pos, i) => {
          return <h1 key={i + 1}>{pos}</h1>;
        })}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I You Like This way Then You Can Follow It

Answer (score 0):

A combination of conditionals and Array can be used.
This is what I came out with after an hour of trial and error

```
if(data){
    return [ //<---yes, array
      // When using arrays, each element should have a key (even single <h1's> like this
      <h1 key="bracket_id">{data.bracket_id}</h1>,
      <ul key="roster_positions">{data.roster_positions.map((pos, i) => {
            return <li key={i + 1}>{pos}</li>;
          })
       }</ul>
    ];
  } else {
    return <h1>loading</h1>
  }
```

Based on [How to concatenate two JSX fragment or variables or string and component (in Reactjs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36912179/how-to-concatenate-two-jsx-fragment-or-variables-or-string-and-component-in-rea)